# Deleting rows in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix, which could look like this:

```
have=rbind(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),ncol=3),c(5,5,5),c(5,5,5),c(5,5,5),c(1,1,1),c(1,1,1))

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    2    3
 [3,]    1    2    3
 [4,]    1    2    3
 [5,]    5    5    5
 [6,]    5    5    5
 [7,]    5    5    5
 [8,]    1    1    1
 [9,]    1    1    1
```

I want to delete rows, if they only appear say 1 or two times. Ideally, I want it to be user-specificed, so if the row only appears N times or less it should be deleted. So, if N=2 then it should delete the last two rows, because they only appear two times:

```
want=rbind(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),ncol=3),c(5,5,5),c(5,5,5),c(5,5,5))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2    3
[5,]    5    5    5
[6,]    5    5    5
[7,]    5    5    5
```

On the other hand, if N=3, then it should return:

```
want_2=rbind(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),ncol=3))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2    3
```

Comment: How many rows/columns does "have" ..have? Are the similar rows, always, in order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rowRemove <- function(x, n) {
  oc <- apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = "\r")
  x[table(oc)[oc] > n, ]
}
rowRemove(have, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
# [3,]    1    2    3
# [4,]    1    2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do that:

**Code**

```
code <- apply(have, 1, paste, collapse = "\t")
rl <- rle(code)
have[code %in% rl$values[rl$lengths > 2], ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
# [3,]    1    2    3
# [4,]    1    2    3
# [5,]    5    5    5
# [6,]    5    5    5
# [7,]    5    5    5
```

**Explanation**

1. First, you get the string representation of each row via `apply`
2. Then you calculate how often each token appears in the whole matrix (via `rle`)
3. Then you select only those rows which do appear more than 2 times

Comment: This may get really messy when the numbers become bigger than single digit (e.g. `12 2 3` will become `1223`, just like `1 22 3` and `1 2 23`). @Julius solves this by using a different collapse.